# How to generate JSON data with PHP?

Tags: php, json

```
CREATE TABLE Posts
{
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(200),
url VARCHAR(200)
}
```

**json.php code**

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from Posts limit 20");
echo '{"posts": [';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$title=$row['title'];
$url=$row['url'];
echo '

{

"title":"'.$title.'",

"url":"'.$url.'"

},'; 
}
echo ']}';

?>
```

I have to generate `results.json` file.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

To generate JSON in PHP, you need only one function, [json_encode()](https://php.net/json_encode).

When working with database, you need to get all the rows into array first. Here is a sample code for mysqli

```
$sql="select * from Posts limit 20"; 
$result = $db->query($sql);
$posts = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

then you can either use this array directly or make it part of another array:

```
echo json_encode($posts);
// or
$response = json_encode([
    'posts' => $posts,
]);
```

if you need to save it in a file then just use `file_put_contents()`

```
file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($posts));
```

Comment: I used this code on my project.  results.json file works well on local host and fails on remote server.  Can you explain why so..

Comment: Fwrite could be turned off in your server settings

Comment: allthough this is great maybe because I'm using PHP 5 now and it wasn't available at the time this answer was posted but you can get rid of the $result= line and inside your while loop just make the mysql_feth_array($sql)

Comment: Please update 1st line to $sql = "select * from Posts limit 20"; , remove mysql_query()

Comment: `fwrite($fp, json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` - uses whitespace to format the JSON. Other constants [here](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: I was about to google for indentation of the json, And I saw your comment. Cheers

Answer (score 73):

Use this:

```
$json_data = json_encode($posts);
file_put_contents('myfile.json', $json_data);
```

> You can create the myfile.json before you run the script.But its not compulsory if you have full sudo privileges(read/write permissions(For of you on Mac).

Here is a working Example:

```
<?php 
  
// data stored in an array called posts
$posts = Array (
    "0" => Array (
        "id" => "01",
        "title" => "Hello",
    ),
    "1" => Array (
        "id" => "02",
        "title" => "Yoyo",
    ),
    "2" => Array (
        "id" => "03",
        "title" => "I like Apples",
    )
);
// encode array to json
$json = json_encode($posts);
$bytes = file_put_contents("myfile.json", $json); //generate json file
echo "Here is the myfile data $bytes.";
?>
```

**Example2:** Another example with a json data and [error handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp).

```
<?php

// Data stored in an array called posts
$posts = [
    [
        "id" => "01",
        "title" => "Hello",
    ],
    [
        "id" => "02",
        "title" => "Yoyo",
    ],
    [
        "id" => "03",
        "title" => "I like Apples",
    ]
];

// Encode array to JSON with formatting
$json = json_encode($posts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Write JSON to file and handle errors
$file = "myfile.json";
if (file_put_contents($file, $json) !== false) {
    echo "Data has been written to $file.";
} else {
    echo "Error occurred while writing to $file.";
}
?>
```

When JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is passed as the second argument to json_encode(), it tells the function to add whitespace and formatting to the generated JSON string. This makes the resulting JSON structure easier to read and understand when viewing it directly.

**Example3:** With SQL data from a server:

```
<?php

// Connect to the database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_password";
$dbname = "your_database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch data from the database
$sql = "SELECT id, name, email FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $users = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $users[] = $row;
    }

    // Encode SQL data to JSON
    $json = json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // Write JSON to file
    $file = "users.json";
    if (file_put_contents($file, $json) !== false) {
        echo "Data has been written to $file.";
    } else {
        echo "Error occurred while writing to $file.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No data found.";
}

// Close the database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: In fact at the comment date there is no need to create the file before saving the data. Though you still have to create the non-existing subfolders, if any, along the saving path. Here is the [official doc for file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) just for convenience.

Comment: Yes,programming languages evolve.My post answer was posted in 2017.You should have posted a new answer with an updated way of doing it instead of just downvoted code that worked in 2017

Comment: There is no change to the snipped you gave. Just the way `file_put_contents` works that I mentioned in my initial comment.

Comment: Ok,thanks,il make the necessary changes to my answer.Thanks Valentine

Answer (score 32):

Insert your fetched values into an array instead of echoing.

Use `file_put_contents()` and insert `json_encode($rows)` into that file, if `$rows` is your data.

Comment: I see your answer was posted before the most upvoted one. If only you had put some example code, you would have gotten many more votes.

Answer (score 10):

If you're pulling dynamic records it's better to have 1 php file that creates a json representation and not create a file each time.

**my_json.php**

```
$array = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'url' => $url
);
            
echo json_encode($array);
```

Then in your script set the path to the file `my_json.php`

Comment: When i try to run this using getJason, i get *Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html* in console.

Comment: @noobcode To fix that, I think you should set a 'Content-Type' header in your 'my_json.php' .

Answer (score 8):

Here i have mentioned the simple syntex for create **json file** and print the array value inside the **json** file in pretty manner.

```
$array = array('name' => $name,'id' => $id,'url' => $url);
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));   // here it will print the array pretty
fclose($fp);
```

Hope it will works for you....

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to decode it :

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Then change the data :

```
$data[0]['activity_name'] = "TENNIS";
// or if you want to change all entries with activity_code "1"
foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    if ($entry['activity_code'] == '1') {
        $data[$key]['activity_name'] = "TENNIS";
    }
}
```

Then re-encode it and save it back in the file:

```
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('jsonFile.json', $newJsonString);
```

[copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17806269)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** function of php and save file with file handling functions such as **[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)** and **[fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)**.

Answer (score 5):

Use PHP's [json methods](http://php.net/json) to create the json then write it to a file with [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite).