# PHP SQL Select statement VS Save to file sever load

Tags: php, mysql, database, webserver

I have a app that loads some json from my php web service. This information may update every hour or so.

Currently every time a user hits the url i requery the database and present the json results.

I am now getting a few more users and want to minimise the load on the server.

Is it better to run this way or run a cron job and read and write from a file.

i.e The cron does the query and saves to a local file.
When the user hits the url i then read the query.

I have tested both and load time is about the same but i wonder how this effects the sever overall?

I don't think memchace is any good due to the amount of data returned.

Any tips or ideas would be great

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much better to create a plain text file that is fetched with your json data in it.

The serverload is much higher if the webserver has to invoke a script (and possible queries too to the database). Many processes are involved in this, even though good webservers try to optimize as much as possible.

A plain file is fetched without much overhead, so go for the cronjob to update the file, as let your app simply request that file, like you suggested yourself.

Comment: Thanks so something like the answer to this is the best thing to do?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php

Comment: Yes. Use json_encode, and write to a file.
Make sure you DON'T pick an extension that might be picked up by the webserver to execute something, like .php. 
For example: You can write a PHP file with only plain HTML: the receiver of the result won't find any difference, but the webserver invokes the PHP process for no reason at all.