# how open a gallery with fancybox on single link? (different html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Hi I've a HTML with  links to  differents albums, and I would like just click on a
simple link to see the first picture from the gallery and then navigate. the problem is that each album is inside from other HTML .. in the galleries.html are just the links to albums.

Example:
galleries.html

```
 <td><a href="albumprueba.php"><img   src="album_prueba1/001.jpg" alt="image19" width="91%" height="56" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="albumprueba2.html"><img    src="album_prueba2/40.jpg" alt="image20" width="99%" height="60"/></a></td>
```

PHP of a gallery:

```
     <a  class="fancyboxi" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Laurea" 
href="album_prueba1/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>">
<img  src="album_prueba1/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>" alt=""   width="19%"/></a>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="manualCall1">Gallery 1</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="manualCall2">Gallery 2</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#manualCall1").click(function () {
            $.getJSON('gallery1.json', function (data) {
                $.fancybox(data, {
                    'index': $(this).data('index'),
                    'padding': 0,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'type': 'image',
                    'changeFade': 0
                });
            });
        });
        $("#manualCall2").click(function () {
            $.getJSON('gallery2.json', function (data) {
                $.fancybox(data, {
                    'index': $(this).data('index'),
                    'padding': 0,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'type': 'image',
                    'changeFade': 0
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**gallery1.json**

```
[{
    "href" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-uK9RF21pLaw/T0-bfLydozI/AAAAAAAAG2Q/CHSPYlMM5hA/w339-h225-n-k/_DSC1774_DRI_PS_small.jpg", 
    "title" : "image title 1"
}, {
    "href" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-B9Fop2ZofLI/T5JZiYzoZKI/AAAAAAAAH5M/0X6lYTa8LAs/w402-h266-n-k/_DSC8800-HDR_corrected_PS_small.jpg",
    "title" : "image title 2"
}, {
    "href" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-MtVcdgn6ZA0/T6LSPnrxfbI/AAAAAAAAIP8/g_BubTeiVbY/w467-h310-n-k/_DSC3079_DRI_PS_transf_small.jpg",
    "title" : "image title 3"
}]
```

**gallery2.json**

```
[{
    "href" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PmHloor5LiU/T7K0_5nq55I/AAAAAAAAIcI/qz8NYty16Yo/w400-h248-n-k/_DSC3336_DRI_PS_defish_small.jpg", 
    "title" : "image title 2 1"
}, {
    "href" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Okzptj_C2cI/T76BCKM4asI/AAAAAAAAKSE/gvPy2sKdbmU/w386-h254-n-k/_DSC3533_DRI_PS_defish_small.jpg",
    "title" : "image title 2 2"
}, {
    "href" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-snm10rkSqDo/T94UWhaFGjI/AAAAAAAALAk/X7b5dVcSKb4/w412-h273-n-k/_DSC3440_DRI_PS_defish_small.jpg",
    "title" : "image title 2 3"
}]
```

Comment: in the example is when you have the images in the same html,no?

Comment: You can get content of different html with Ajax and place it to same html of your page

Comment: mmm sorry but i'm a beginner and i don't understand.. :S

Comment: I'm continuing without understand.. :( , inside the DIV I should put all the link albums?

Comment: No, this line $('#placeholder').html(data); update divs inner html. this html contains lines like this <a href="images/02.jpg" rel="gallery" class="fancygallery"></a>. and $.get method download files, that contain the html

Comment: ok, but the photos are generates by php when I clik on an album, therefore, at the beginning there aren't pictures to show, and depending on what album clickes are generated photos in an album or another

Comment: Yes, work fine:) but.. inside json file I must introduce the photos manually. I can not introduce PHP to traverse a directory and get the photos inside?

Comment: because each album contains over 100 photos :S

Comment: You can replase *.json files with url-s to php json generators that will write json to response

Comment: Sorry to abuse your trust, but I have never seen as json file work, did not know of its existence. : (, Could you give me an example?

Comment: Look here http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/php-creating-json-response-a-real-world-example/

Comment: And here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php

Comment: this is my PHP to get photos:

   $path = "./Libro Fez/";
           
           $dh = opendir($path); 
           $archivos = array();
           while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { 
                  if($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
                          if(substr($file, -4) == '.jpg') $archivos[] = $file;
                  } 
           } 
           closedir($dh); 
           sort($archivos); 
      while($imagen_a_empezar<=$imagen_a_terminar){
        
        if($imagen_a_empezar>=$total_imagenes) break;
  
        ?>

Comment: <a  class="fancyboxi" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Laurea" href="Libro Fez/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>"><img  src="Libro Fez/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>" alt=""   width="19%"/></a>
       
        <?php
        $imagen_a_empezar++;
 }