# How create Json by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate .json file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php)

I want to use php to create a json like below. it will  return a string json as a response from result sql query. How do I do?

```
{"Orders":[  
            {"DeliveryId":"DeliveryId","CustomerName":"CustomerName","PhoneNumber":"PhoneNumber","Address":"Address"},  
            {"DeliveryId":"DeliveryId","CustomerName":"CustomerName","PhoneNumber":"PhoneNumber","Address":"Address"}               
]
}
```

my code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("mysql12.000webhost.com","a4602996_longvan","longvan2012");
mysql_select_db("a4602996_lv"); 
$id=$_POST[user];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from testlongvan where Status = 'PACKED'" ); 

$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
$json['Orders'][]=$row;
}
}

//while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
//$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($json)); 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

But when use my code i recieve result, don't result i want:

> {"Orders":[
>   ["longvan","10/12/2012","Be34433jh","Long Van","115 Pham Viet Chanh, quan Binh Thanh","http://longvansolution.tk/image/sample.jpg","PACKED","0909056788"],
>       ["takeshi","24/12/2012","BF6464633","Vn-zoom","16 nguyen cuu van, quan binh thanh","http://longvansolution.tk/image/hoadon3.jpg","PACKED","098897657"]
>       ]}
>   Can you help me!

Comment: Can you show us your SQL query?

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: $sql=mysql_query("select DeliveryID,CustomerName,PhoneNumber,Address  from testlongvan where Status = 'PACKED'" );

Comment: @Takeshi, please add that to your question via the edit button.

Comment: @Kolink pardon my ignorance, how is that not JSON?

Comment: @Supericy Well, it is now. Before the edit there were `=` in place of `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to do that.

And your JSON format is invalid. Use `:` instead of `=`

Comment: Please leave a comment for your downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
// SERVER SIDE
<?php
    //... create array
    //....Obviously you would use your own SQL link and query
    $animals = array();
    $result = @mysqli_query('YOUR DB LINK', 'YOUR QUERY');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        array_push($animals, array(
            'animal' => $row['animal'],
            'sound'  => $row['sound']
    ));
    }
?>

// CLIENT SIDE
<html>
<script>
    // RETURN FROM PHP PAGE ECHO VIA AJAX PERHAPS //
    var animals = <?php echo json_encode($animals) ?>;

    $.each(animals, function (i, elem) {
        console.log(elem.animal + " makes a " + elem.sound);
    });
</script>
</html>
```