# How to update/edit a JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is my **JSON**

```
[
   {
      "activity_code":"1",
      "activity_name":"FOOTBALL"
   },
   {
      "activity_code":"2",
      "activity_name":"CRICKET"
   }
]
```

I need to update `{"activity_code":"1","activity_name":"FOOTBALL"}` to `{"activity_code":"1","activity_name":"TENNIS"}` based on `activity_code`

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

First, you need to decode it :

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Then change the data :

```
$data[0]['activity_name'] = "TENNIS";
// or if you want to change all entries with activity_code "1"
foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    if ($entry['activity_code'] == '1') {
        $data[$key]['activity_name'] = "TENNIS";
    }
}
```

Then re-encode it and save it back in the file:

```
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('jsonFile.json', $newJsonString);
```

Comment: here '$data[1]' 1 representing node value or activity code?

Comment: I corrected it, `$data[0]` is actually `{"activity_code":"1","activity_name":"FOOTBALL"}`

Comment: i need base on code for example {"activity_code":"TG3","activity_name":"FOOTBALL"} in this case i need to update ACTIVITY_CODE - TG3 to TENNIS

Comment: some thing like `where activity_code='TG3'` is it possible?

Comment: This is `sql` ! See my edit :)

Comment: thanks.. is it possible to go direct to the code with out for loop? something like sql query?

Comment: This is nonsens, you don't have a database, you can't do a SQL query !

Comment: i asking you is it possible some thing like `$data['activity_name'='TG3']['activity_name'] = "TENNIS";`

Comment: If you edit the json file logged in as root can php still write to it?

Comment: @zachdyer As long as you don't change the file permissions it will not have any effect. Make sure that your server user (www or www-data typically) can open this file and you are good to go.

Comment: Can I get help? When I save the new JSON string, the .json file loses everything except for the field updated.

Comment: I Solved it. I had a function do the update while the JSON was loaded on the outside. The variables were out of scope, and since the JSON was hardcoded in the update function, it was just overwriting the entire file with only the key and value I updated

Comment: @Brewal could help me, same problem as above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647214/why-value-is-not-updated-in-json-using-php-and-jquery