# Update JSON File Using PHP and BackboneJS

Tags: php, javascript, json, backbone.js, mamp

Trying to be able to have my website so that I can update a JSON file when I edit a cell using BackgridJS (backgridjs.com). In order to save the file to the server, this is the code I  am using:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function () {
Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
this.on("change", function (model, options) {
  if (options && options.save === false) return;
  model.save();
    });
  }
});
```

I want it to apply the change to the JSON file, but I figured it would be easier to use PHP. I read about how to do this on [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806224/how-to-update-edit-json-file-using-php) but since I am just beginning to learn PHP, I'm very confused. I keep trying to implement that code into my file, but nothing happens when I save the cell. I'm using MAMP as a localhost.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi John and welcome to SO. Could you also post up your PHP code. Are you also sure that the PHP script is being run when the model is saved?

Comment: @DavidBarker Thanks for replying. I don't have any PHP code right now. Just took what they wrote in the other StackOverflow question. Not sure how to combine the two together.

Comment: @DavidBarker Using this PHP code, but that just takes over the whole JSON file instead of updating it to the change.                                                `<?php
         
       $jsonString = file_get_contents('examples/olympics.json');
  $data[0]['country'] = "USA";
  // or if you want to change all entries with year "2016"
  foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
      if ($entry['year'] == '2016') {
        $data[$key]['country'] = "USA";
    }
}

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('examples/olympics.json', $newJsonString);
 ?>`

Comment: You can't edit directly a json string in PHP, first you must decode it like this to get an array you can edit: `<?php $jsonString = file_get_contents('examples/olympics.json'); $data = json_decode($jsonString,true);`

Comment: @Ingro Awesome. That works great. Thanks for that. Now I need to make it so that it updates to whatever the user inputs.

Comment: @Ingro So basically, I understand that I must decode the JSON file to get an array, and then use PHP to update the array. From there, I want to be able to change a cell, and have it update the array accordingly. For example, I want to be able to actually input "USA" in the cell, and have it update the array and have the array pushed to the JSON file after I hit return.

Comment: Well there are multiple ways to achieve this. If you don't have a restful api backing your model on the server I suggest you just to make an ajax call using jQuery with the current model's data to your server and just update your json file with PHP.

Comment: @Ingro How would I do this? Sorry for so many questions, just beginning to learn how all this stuff works.

Comment: @Ingro Any tutorials I can follow?

Comment: One tutorial about PHP and Backbone working togheter [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/)(it's a little outdated but should do), another one more focused on the basics of backbone [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1367/part-1-backbonejs-deconstructed)(highly raccomended)

Comment: @Ingro Thanks for those. Although they seem super helpful, I feel it's a little much for my problem I'm having here. Is there any part of the tutorial that describes what I want to do? I basically want `$newJsonString` to equal the change made in a cell.

Comment: @Ingro I found out how to get the full JSON file text, once I hit return using Backbone. I tested this by creating an alert like so: `alert(JSON.stringify(this));` This alerts me of what I want JSON file to look like, but does not actually update the file (just gives me the text in an alert). How can I make it so this actually updates the file using PHP?

Comment: You could send it to your PHP script with jQuery like this: `var data = JSON.stringify(this); $.ajax({url:"update.php",type:"POST",data:data});` And then in your PHP page you could access the data you send with the `$_REQUEST` array.

Comment: @Ingro Thanks for all the help. Only problem is, I don't have a PHP page. It's an HTML page.

Comment: @Ingro Feel like we're getting close here. I really appreciate the help. Just confused with the `update.php` part and the `$_REQUEST` parts since I don't have a PHP page.

Comment: In your question you said you wanted to use PHP to edit your json file, so you should create a PHP file to receive the data from your page. The $_REQUEST array contains all the data you pass to your script via the POST request, so you could update your json file with that data.

Comment: @Ingro So how do I do this? I created a file called update.php and put this in it `<?php echo $_REQUEST ["data"]

  $jsonString = file_get_contents('examples/olympics.json');
        $data = json_decode($jsonString,true); 
        $data = data;
        $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
        file_put_contents('examples/olympics.json', $newJsonString); 
  
 
 
 ?>` But it's not working. I assume it doesn't know the variable `data` so how do I make it know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Ingro, this is the solution. In the HTML with Backbone embedded:

```
var data1 = JSON.stringify(this); 
    obj = JSON.parse(data1);
    $.ajax({url:"update.php",type:"POST",data:{
    "data3":obj

    }});
```

and in the PHP file:

```
     <?php $jsonString = file_get_contents('examples/olympics.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonString,true); 
    $data3 = $_REQUEST ["data3"];
    $data = $data3;
    $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('examples/olympics.json', $newJsonString); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Glad you finally manage to make it work! Don't forget to read some tutorial to improve your workflow tough!