# PHP - Load JSON, edit and save

Tags: php, json

I load JSON from file:

```
{ "timestampRead": [11, 22, 33], "timestampCurrent": [66, 77, 88] }
```

to PHP:

```
$local_json = json_decode(file_get_contents('/Temp/chat-users.json'));
```

and I don't know how I can:

1. update all values in timestampRead (`$local_json->timestampRead[] = '99'?`)
2. update one value in timestampCurrent (`$local_json->timestampCurrent[2] = '33'`)
3. save updated json to file (`$local_json array to json`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update/edit .json file using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806224/how-to-update-edit-json-file-using-php)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Did it work?  If not, in what way did it not work?

Comment: Clues - 1 and 2 work.  3 - what do you think the opposite of json_decode might be?  And what do you think the opposite of file_get_contents might be?  Final clue - php.net

Comment: have you tried those?

Answer (score 2):

1) update all values in timestampRead: `$local_json->timestampRead = array( [your comma separated values] );`

2) update one value in timestampCurrent: `$local_json->timestampCurrent[2] = '33';` (correct)

3) save updated json to file: `file_put_contents('path/to/file', json_encode($local_json));`

Answer (score 1):

Once have the json data loaded into a variable, you can access each property as you would a normal class:

```
$local_json->timestampRead = $new_timestampRead;
$local_json->timestampCurrent[an_index] = "whatever you want";
```

To save the data back to a file, you can use the counter part of `file_get_contents()` called [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents):

```
file_put_contents("path/to/file", $local_json);
```

Comment: $local_json->timestampRead = $new_timestampRead; - but this code change my array to string. I want change all array value to one new value

Comment: @KubaŻukowski - if `$new_timestampRead` is an array, that is what will be used.

Comment: I know, but in this example I must know how much elements have this array, make and…. you know. So I can't change all values on array?

Comment: @KubaŻukowski - I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you are trying to do... Could you please add some more detail to your original question?