# modify json object in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json file which is read by php and i want to change one object of the json file using php now my code looks like this but it doesn't work so how should I do? (the obj_name in the son object should be modified to $name)

```
<?php
   $json = $_POST['myobj'];
   $data = json_decode($json,true);
   $name = xxxxxxxxx;
     $data['obj_name'] = "$name";
     #json = json_encode($data);
     $filename = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
     $file = fopen($filename,'w+');
     fwrite($file, $json);
     fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Show us what `print_r($data)` gives you, we need to see what the object looks like.

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806224/how-to-update-edit-json-file-using-php) is helpful

Comment: ahhh i miswrite $  as #... stupid error, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` is commenting out your code and it should be a `$` to make it a variable.

So, change this:

```
#json = json_encode($data);
```

to this:

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```