# Why value is not updated in JSON using PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I stuck at the JSON file whereby the value is not updated.

Reference:

1. [How to update/edit a JSON file using PHP [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806224/how-to-update-edit-a-json-file-using-php)
2. [Add, Update, Delete and Read JSON Data/File in PHP](https://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2017/05/add-update-delete-read-json-file-php.html)
3. [Modifying a JSON file with PHP](https://thisinterestsme.com/modifying-json-file-php/)

console.log
[image]

JSON (../assets/data/maintenance.json)

```
[
    {
        "maintenance_status":"off"
    }
]
```

PHP (file_update.php)

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('../assets/data/maintenance.json');  // able to read file
$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

$newValue = $_POST['newValue'];
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
    $json_arr[$key]['maintenance_status'] = $newValue;
}

file_put_contents('../assets/data/maintenance.json', json_encode($json_arr));
echo json_encode($json_arr); // return [{"maintenance_status":"on"}] at jQuery success response
?>
```

jQuery

```
$('.maintenance-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.maintenance-toggle').toggleClass('on');
    if ($('.maintenance-toggle').hasClass('on')){
        console.log('on'); // line 84
        updateValue("on");
    }
    else if ($('.maintenance-toggle').hasClass('off')){
        console.log('off'); // line 88
        updateValue("off");
    }
});

function updateValue(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue); // line 98
    $.ajax({
        url : '../src/files/file_update.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data: { 
            newValue: newValue
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response); // success since received result from echo php but not update the value in JSON
        },
        error: function(e){

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Without debugging information we can't help you effectively. Check devtools to ensure the AJAX request is successful, and check your server logs to ensure the PHP is working. I'd suggest also checking that the service running the PHP on the server has the necessary file access rights to modify files in the given folder. In general, though, I'd advise against writing to the file system from a web server - it's slow and you will run in to locking issues very quickly. Use a database.

Comment: You can also check what `file_put_contents(...)` returns. It will either return the number of bytes written on success, or `false` on error. If it returns `false`, you can return an error message instead so you can tell the js code and the user that the update failed.

Comment: The PHP code works, so assuming you can actually access `../assets/data/maintenance.json` from the script, there is no problem there. What makes you think the file is no being updated