# Angularjs saving user input data and generate it to a json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am pretty new to angularjs and web app development. I'm making a simple web app. First, it reads default settings from a json file. Then on the web, users are able to change these settings. However, I am stuck on how to save those changes made by users and how to generate them to a new json file. I don't know what I should put in the controller. I tried different methods found online but none of them worked. Please assist.

**app.js** - I only did the read file part but need the save file part.

```
var app1 = angular.module("myApp", [])
    app1.controller("myAppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('src/default.json').then(function(response){
            $scope.messes = response.data;
        });
    });
```

Comment: you want to generate the new json file on server side or client side?

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know the difference between those two.

Comment: But I think it's going to be on server side.@MarkoCen

Answer (score 1):

Logically you should work with your server side processing in this situation. Write a server api (in php, node.js, java etc) to accept a json, convert into json file and stores somewhere and returns you the downloadable link of the physical json file.

So in your case:

```
$http.get('src/default.json').then(function(response){
  $scope.messes = response.data;
  // perform your logic, create a json and send to server
});
```

Let your server do the heavy lifting of processing. It's also important to consider what is the size of the json data which may affect your browser user experience badly.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't really know how to save the changes made by the users. May you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to generate files on client side(no server side logic needed) is by using HTML5 [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File):

```
var app1 = angular.module("myApp", [])
app1.controller("myAppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('src/default.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.messes = response.data;
    });

    $scope.generateJSONFile = function(){
        var jsonStr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.messes));
        var blob = new Blob([jsonStr], {type: "application/json"});
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var a = document.createElement('A');
        a.download = "default.json";
        a.href = url;

        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }
});
```

[live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qM9xbMXHeGOFXWnZCvtN?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. So what if I want it to save those changes after users click on "save" button on the web page, would it be the same as what you did above? Also may you please explain which piece of code actually does the saving work?

Comment: @CarrieShen I add a live example on plunker, see my updates, you just need to call `generateJSONFile` in click handler, in `generateJSONFile`, it create a `blob` based on the json string, then creat a url object which could be downloaded by browser based on that blob,

Comment: That works great. Is there any way I can do it on server side? I don't really want users to download the json file every time they click on the button. I prefer to have the file only available to the developer for the future usage.

Comment: different platform has different approach, if your server built on PHP, you could check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php), and please mark my post as answer if my post help you resolve the issue:)