# JSON + PHP error not too sure what I am doing wrong I am following a video tutorial. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, syntax-error

So here is the error that I am receiving.

```
VM10728:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (timeline.php:175)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Here is the code on the main page using the AJAX Get

```
  <div class="timelineposts">
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>The content of your modal.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "../api/posts",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '',
                        success: function(r) {
                                var posts = JSON.parse(r)
                                $.each(posts, function(index) {
                                        $('.timelineposts').html(
                                                $('.timelineposts').html() + '<blockquote><p>'+posts[index].PostBody+'</p><footer>Posted by '+posts[index].PostedBy+' on '+posts[index].PostDate+'<button class="btn btn-default" data-id="'+posts[index].PostId+'" type="button" style="color:#eb3b60;background-image:url(&quot;none&quot;);background-color:transparent;"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-aos="flip-right"></i><span> '+posts[index].Likes+' Likes</span></button><button class="btn btn-default comment" type="button" data-postid="'+posts[index].PostId+'" style="color:#eb3b60;background-image:url(&quot;none&quot;);background-color:transparent;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash" style="color:#f9d616;"></i><span style="color:#f9d616;"> Comments</span></button></footer></blockquote>'
                                        )
                                        $('[data-postid]').click(function() {
                                                var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-postid');
                                                $.ajax({
                                                        type: "GET",
                                                        url: "../api/comments?postid=" + $(this).attr('data-postid'),
                                                        processData: false,
                                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                                        data: '',
                                                        success: function(r) {
                                                                var res = JSON.parse(r)
                                                                showCommentsModal(res);
                                                        },
                                                        error: function(r) {
                                                                console.log(r)
                                                        }
                                                });
                                        });
                                        $('[data-id]').click(function() {
                                                var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                                $.ajax({
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "../api/likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                                                        processData: false,
                                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                                        data: '',
                                                        success: function(r) {
                                                                var res = JSON.parse(r)
                                                                $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"']").html(' <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" data-aos="flip-right"></i><span> '+res.Likes+' Likes</span>')
                                                        },
                                                        error: function(r) {
                                                                console.log(r)
                                                        }
                                                });
                                        })
                                })
                        },
                        error: function(r) {
                                console.log(r)
                        }
                });
        });
        function showCommentsModal(res) {
                $('.modal').modal('show')
                var output = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        output += res[i].Comment;
                        output += " ~ ";
                        output += res[i].CommentedBy;
                        output += "<hr />";
                }
                $('.modal-body').html(output)
        }
    </script>
```

And here is where the JSON array is kept

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {

        if ($_GET['url'] == "auth") {

        } else if ($_GET['url'] == "users") {

        } else if ($_GET['url'] == "comments" && isset($_GET['postid'])) {
                $output = "";
                $comments = $db->query('SELECT comments.comment, users.username FROM comments, users WHERE post_id = :postid AND comments.user_id = users.id', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                $output .= "[";
                foreach($comments as $comment) {
                        $output .= "{";
                        $output .= '"Comment": "'.$comment['comment'].'",';
                        $output .= '"CommentedBy": "'.$comment['username'].'"';
                        $output .= "},";
                        //echo $comment['comment']." ~ ".$comment['username']."<hr />";
                }
                $output = substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-1);
                $output .= "]";
                echo $output;

        } else if ($_GET['url'] == "posts") {

                $token = $_COOKIE['SNID'];

                $userid = $db->query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($token)))[0]['user_id'];

                $followingposts = $db->query('SELECT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.likes, users.`username` FROM users, posts, followers
                WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
                AND users.id = posts.user_id
                AND follower_id = :userid
                ORDER BY posts.likes DESC;', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                $response = "[";
                foreach($followingposts as $post) {

                        $response .= "{";
                                $response .= '"PostId": '.$post['id'].',';
                                $response .= '"PostBody": "'.$post['body'].'",';
                                $response .= '"PostedBy": "'.$post['username'].'",';
                                $response .= '"PostDate": "'.$post['posted_at'].'",';
                                $response .= '"Likes": '.$post['likes'].'';
                        $response .= "},";


                }
                $response = substr($response, 0, strlen($response)-1);
                $response .= "]";

                http_response_code(200);
                echo $response;

        }
                }
```

I don't really understand what wen't wrong I have been following the whole tutorial for the last few days and now I'm just stopped dead in my tracks here is the link to the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyaDoQk5y1A

I have never tried to include JSON in my websites before so I thought I would give it a go as to learn something new. But I cannot find anything online that is able to help me with the issue that I am having.

Thanks in advance.

- Jonny.

EDIT my sql table

ID  body        posted_at   user_id   likes  topics
1   Hello 123   01/09/2018  1           0    NULL
2   Hello 321   01/09/2018  1           0    NULL
3   Hello 321   01/09/2018  2           0    NULL

Comment: Can I suggest you ditch that tutorial and make use of `json_encode` and `json_decode`, I haven't manually created JSON in the last 10 years and with those two functions available I highly recommend you don't do it either :)

Comment: @Dale I could try was using the tutorial as a way of learning but if there is an easier way then I shall try that. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm quite shocked to see that being done in a tutorial from 2017! If I were you I'd try to finish the tutorial but take it with a pinch of salt, try and adapt the good bits to your needs and always see what other techniques are out there :)

Comment: As an effort to answer... does this happen when you visit the `/posts` URL ? in that case it looks like the code isn't creating the initial `[` it's just outputting the final `]`

Comment: @Dale On the posts page it is showing only the closing square bracket. so just this ]

Comment: That's because it never creates the opening one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate .json file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php)

Comment: @Dale Do you know why that is, the .= should append on it?

Comment: There is no `$response = '['`; in that block of code... Ignore me I've gone code blind

Comment: You're right I couldn't see it, yes you have nailed the issue

Comment: @IncredibleHat Why are none of the rows looping on as its all in the for loop

Comment: @IncredibleHat I have added my sql table

Comment: @Dale I have fixed posts but comment is still not working But there are literally no differences between the 2.

Comment: Sorry pal, if you're going to learn from a bad tutorial, you're also going to run into issues

Comment: @Dale Thanks for you help mate :)

Comment: @Dale, Never mind i have just fixed it I had an incorrectly placed comma :( Wow I feel like a fool thank you for trying to help tho :)

Comment: no worries, its often the case :) cant see the wood for the trees (I couldnt see the $response = '[';) :)