# How to download a json file and save it as a js file on server?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to save [this json](https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/daily.json) as a js file with a date with this format:

```
1-5-20_us_states.js
```

The json would then be inserted in the saved file within:

```
var data = ...json data... ;
```

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15617609/1018804) which it's ok to open the file but how to do the rest then?

Following that answer we should:

```
$url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/daily.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: if you want to save JSON, no need to decode it before saving it

Comment: @JaromandaX how would I insert it within the variable and save it as a js file?

Comment: @JaromandaX updated the question, forgot to actually include the json link I'm talking about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate .json file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php)

Comment: "insert it within the variable" - you're writing to a file, you don't need to insert it into a variable ... just write `"var data =" . $json` to the file (if my PHP skills are correct)

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR - he doesn't WANT a JSON file, he wants a JS file

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly. Not thanks @ Anandhukrishna VR. Could anyone paste an answer if you know how to?

Comment: do you know how to write a file in PHP? and why are you copying this data?

Comment: @JaromandaX Not really, but I could read something like this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp thing is I don't know how to combine that with writing that json data within that var as per the question and save the js file with that date format I'm afraid

Comment: `file_put_contents ("1-5-20_us_states.js", "var data =" . $json)` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX looks promising could you place that into a complete answer based on the question code please? Might be useful for future users too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're getting JSON, you don't need to decode it before writing it as a `.js` file since the JSON syntax is basically just like using javascript

prepend `var data =` to the string you get and you can write this to a file

Something like

```
$url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/daily.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents ("1-5-20_us_states.js", "var data =" . $json);
```