# How to grab all files which have a specific word in it

Tags: php, arrays

For a flat file blogsystem, i use `.txt` files in which all the data are stored.
A txt file looks like this:

```
id_123456 // 1st line is id line
sport     // 2nd line is category line
...
```

What i need is an array of txt files which have a certain category name.
This is what i have so far:

```
$filterthis = 'club';
$filematches = [];

$blogfiles = glob($dir.'/*.txt'); // read all the blogfiles (txt files)

foreach($blogfiles as $file) { // loop through all te files
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // file in to an array
    $category = $lines[1]; // the category line

    if (in_array($category, $filterthis)) {
        $filematches[] = $file; // array with all the files which have category "club"??
    }
```

So `$filematches` should contain all the files which contain category "club", but i do not succeed in that

Comment: was there a point where you wished that you'd used a database instead?

Comment: In `if (in_array($category, $filterthis))` - which of these two do you think is an array? According to the example contents the 2nd line is the category ( string ) and you are looking for `$filterthis` ( string ) - neither would appear to be an array. Perhaps `if( $category==$filterthis ){/* add to output */}`

Comment: i know this is wrong, but how can i achieve what i want?

Comment: Why don't you save the information as JSON? I made a video game in that format so I didn't have to use a database. Check out this link for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code

```
$filterthis = 'club';
$filematches = [];

$blogfiles = glob($dir.'/*.txt'); // read all the blogfiles (txt files)

foreach($blogfiles as $file) { // loop through all te files
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // file in to an array
    $category = $lines[1]; // the category line

    if (in_array($category, $filterthis)) {
        $filematches[] = $file; // array with all the files which have category "club"??
    }

$filterthis = 'club';
```

The above variable "$filterthis" is a type String

```
$category = $lines[1]; // the category line
```

The above variable "$category" is also string (as you are picking up entire line from lines array)

and then your condition

```
 if (in_array($category, $filterthis))
```

You are using in_array function which accept first argument as needle and second argument an array but you provided string as both arguments

in your if condition, change the condition

```
if($category == $filterthis)
```

Then it will work

Comment: `"am not sure if you are able to read this kind of text, But  to me it seems cool, So I just used it to show my profile description. That's all for now "` '-)

Comment: Unfortunately, `if($category == $filterthis) {
   $filtercategorymatches[] = $file;
  }` does not work for me~

Comment: you used the $buffer variable to compare but  I think you should use $category ?

Comment: sorry, yes `$buffer` should be `$category`

Comment: OMG that's my profile text, I forgot that, @ProfessorAbronsius that's nice lol :)

Comment: As you say @BlackXero - that is from your profile text!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($blogfiles as $file) { // loop through all te files
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // file in to an array
    $category = $lines[1]; // the category line

    if(strpos(strtolower($category), $filterthis) !== FALSE) { // strtolower; category word not case sensitive
        $filematches[] = $file; // this gives you the desired array 
    }
```