# How to send input from forms in html to javascript to my json file

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, forms

I want to send the input from id="question" and id="answer" to a javascript file to a json file and I want to store multiple questions with their answers , I don't know how to do that could anyone help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Study App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <label class="Question_text" for="question">Question</label>
        <input class="Question_input" id="question" placeholder="Enter your question" required>
        <label class="answer_text" for="answer">Answer</label>
        <input class="answer_input" id="answer" placeholder=" Enter your answer" required>
        <button class="Reset_btn" type="reset">Clear Fields</button>
        <button class="enter_question" type="submit">Enter Question</button>
    </form>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you cannot send data to js files.. who are the actors in your game? you showed an html form having some inputs that will be sent with an http request made to an url that should be defined in form attribute `action`. But you didn't define any and you didn't better explain what you wish to do. You probably need a server side action in charge of processing those requests but your question is too vague so far

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get the values from the input like this

```
var q = document.getElementById("question")
var ans = document.getElementById("answer")
```

and then vanilla javascript cannot write to a fiile so you will  need to use [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php) or [node.js](https://attacomsian.com/blog/nodejs-read-write-json-files) or for local use you can use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [localstorage](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=localstorage) elsewise you can use some kind of database

Comment: yoo bro it's storing the things in type in my input function its storing this
input#question.Question_input input#answer.answer_input
input#question.Question_input input#answer.answer_input



How to fix

Comment: then you can get the values after the buttons is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can the below JS function. 
You have to call the function in `onSubmit` attribute of HTML form.

```js
function exportToJSON() {
  const userQuestion = document.getElementById("question").value;
  const userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
  
  const data = {
    questions: 
      {
        question: userQuestion,
        answer: userAnswer
      }
  };

  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ')], {
    type: "text/plain"
  }));
  a.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Study App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" onSubmit="exportToJSON()">
        <label class="Question_text" for="question">Question</label>
        <input class="Question_input" id="question" placeholder="Enter your question" required>
        <label class="answer_text" for="answer">Answer</label>
        <input class="answer_input" id="answer" placeholder="Enter your answer" required>
        <button class="Reset_btn" type="reset">Clear Fields</button>
        <button class="enter_question" type="submit">Enter Question</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it working but why is it downloading a file

Comment: This is your question → 'How to send input from forms in HTML to JavaScript to my JSON file'. Right? So, the file is a JSON file that stores the value entered in those form elements.

Comment: Yea but i Alderdy have a json file in vs code i want it to go there